# Need help pausing tilt.js glare while the card flips over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a collectible card game this is my first HTML, CSS and JS project. So far I've managed to get the cards to flip over and added tilt.js into my project however the built in glare doesn't "pause" whilst card is flipping so as it flips you are left with faint white box until the card flips fully which doesn't look nice at all.

I thought to myself that I could make an if statement saying something along the lines of "if card not 'flat' glare=false" but I have no idea how to put that into JS, if anyone can help or if anyone has another solution would be appreciated :)

```js
function flip(event) {
  var element = event.currentTarget;
  if (element.className === "card") {
    if (element.style.transform == "rotateY(180deg)") {
      element.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
    } else {
      element.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
    }
  }
};

var VanillaTilt = (function() {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * Created by Sergiu Șandor (micku7zu) on 1/27/2017.
   * Original idea: https://github.com/gijsroge/tilt.js
   * MIT License.
   * Version 1.7.0
   */

  class VanillaTilt {
    constructor(element, settings = {}) {
      if (!(element instanceof Node)) {
        throw ("Can't initialize VanillaTilt because " + element + " is not a Node.");
      }

      this.width = null;
      this.height = null;
      this.clientWidth = null;
      this.clientHeight = null;
      this.left = null;
      this.top = null;

      // for Gyroscope sampling
      this.gammazero = null;
      this.betazero = null;
      this.lastgammazero = null;
      this.lastbetazero = null;

      this.transitionTimeout = null;
      this.updateCall = null;
      this.event = null;

      this.updateBind = this.update.bind(this);
      this.resetBind = this.reset.bind(this);

      this.element = element;
      this.settings = this.extendSettings(settings);

      this.reverse = this.settings.reverse ? -1 : 1;
      this.glare = VanillaTilt.isSettingTrue(this.settings.glare);
      this.glarePrerender = VanillaTilt.isSettingTrue(this.settings["glare-prerender"]);
      this.fullPageListening = VanillaTilt.isSettingTrue(this.settings["full-page-listening"]);
      this.gyroscope = VanillaTilt.isSettingTrue(this.settings.gyroscope);
      this.gyroscopeSamples = this.settings.gyroscopeSamples;

      this.elementListener = this.getElementListener();

      if (this.glare) {
        this.prepareGlare();
      }

      if (this.fullPageListening) {
        this.updateClientSize();
      }

      this.addEventListeners();
      this.updateInitialPosition();
    }

    static isSettingTrue(setting) {
      return setting === "" || setting === true || setting === 1;
    }

    /**
     * Method returns element what will be listen mouse events
     * @return {Node}
     */
    getElementListener() {
      if (this.fullPageListening) {
        return window.document;
      }

      if (typeof this.settings["mouse-event-element"] === "string") {
        const mouseEventElement = document.querySelector(this.settings["mouse-event-element"]);

        if (mouseEventElement) {
          return mouseEventElement;
        }
      }

      if (this.settings["mouse-event-element"] instanceof Node) {
        return this.settings["mouse-event-element"];
      }

      return this.element;
    }

    /**
     * Method set listen methods for this.elementListener
     * @return {Node}
     */
    addEventListeners() {
      this.onMouseEnterBind = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
      this.onMouseMoveBind = this.onMouseMove.bind(this);
      this.onMouseLeaveBind = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
      this.onWindowResizeBind = this.onWindowResize.bind(this);
      this.onDeviceOrientationBind = this.onDeviceOrientation.bind(this);

      this.elementListener.addEventListener("mouseenter", this.onMouseEnterBind);
      this.elementListener.addEventListener("mouseleave", this.onMouseLeaveBind);
      this.elementListener.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMoveBind);

      if (this.glare || this.fullPageListening) {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResizeBind);
      }

      if (this.gyroscope) {
        window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.onDeviceOrientationBind);
      }
    }

    /**
     * Method remove event listeners from current this.elementListener
     */
    removeEventListeners() {
      this.elementListener.removeEventListener("mouseenter", this.onMouseEnterBind);
      this.elementListener.removeEventListener("mouseleave", this.onMouseLeaveBind);
      this.elementListener.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMoveBind);

      if (this.gyroscope) {
        window.removeEventListener("deviceorientation", this.onDeviceOrientationBind);
      }

      if (this.glare || this.fullPageListening) {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResizeBind);
      }
    }

    destroy() {
      clearTimeout(this.transitionTimeout);
      if (this.updateCall !== null) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.updateCall);
      }

      this.reset();

      this.removeEventListeners();
      this.element.vanillaTilt = null;
      delete this.element.vanillaTilt;

      this.element = null;
    }

    onDeviceOrientation(event) {
      if (event.gamma === null || event.beta === null) {
        return;
      }

      this.updateElementPosition();

      if (this.gyroscopeSamples > 0) {
        this.lastgammazero = this.gammazero;
        this.lastbetazero = this.betazero;

        if (this.gammazero === null) {
          this.gammazero = event.gamma;
          this.betazero = event.beta;
        } else {
          this.gammazero = (event.gamma + this.lastgammazero) / 2;
          this.betazero = (event.beta + this.lastbetazero) / 2;
        }

        this.gyroscopeSamples -= 1;
      }

      const totalAngleX = this.settings.gyroscopeMaxAngleX - this.settings.gyroscopeMinAngleX;
      const totalAngleY = this.settings.gyroscopeMaxAngleY - this.settings.gyroscopeMinAngleY;

      const degreesPerPixelX = totalAngleX / this.width;
      const degreesPerPixelY = totalAngleY / this.height;

      const angleX = event.gamma - (this.settings.gyroscopeMinAngleX + this.gammazero);
      const angleY = event.beta - (this.settings.gyroscopeMinAngleY + this.betazero);

      const posX = angleX / degreesPerPixelX;
      const posY = angleY / degreesPerPixelY;

      if (this.updateCall !== null) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.updateCall);
      }

      this.event = {
        clientX: posX + this.left,
        clientY: posY + this.top,
      };

      this.updateCall = requestAnimationFrame(this.updateBind);
    }

    onMouseEnter() {
      this.updateElementPosition();
      this.element.style.willChange = "transform";
      this.setTransition();
    }

    onMouseMove(event) {
      if (this.updateCall !== null) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.updateCall);
      }

      this.event = event;
      this.updateCall = requestAnimationFrame(this.updateBind);
    }

    onMouseLeave() {
      this.setTransition();

      if (this.settings.reset) {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.resetBind);
      }
    }

    reset() {
      this.event = {
        clientX: this.left + this.width / 2,
        clientY: this.top + this.height / 2
      };

      if (this.element && this.element.style) {
        this.element.style.transform = `perspective(${this.settings.perspective}px) ` +
          `rotateX(0deg) ` +
          `rotateY(0deg) ` +
          `scale3d(1, 1, 1)`;
      }

      this.resetGlare();
    }

    resetGlare() {
      if (this.glare) {
        this.glareElement.style.transform = "rotate(180deg) translate(-50%, -50%)";
        this.glareElement.style.opacity = "0";
      }
    }

    updateInitialPosition() {
      if (this.settings.startX === 0 && this.settings.startY === 0) {
        return;
      }

      this.onMouseEnter();

      if (this.fullPageListening) {
        this.event = {
          clientX: (this.settings.startX + this.settings.max) / (2 * this.settings.max) * this.clientWidth,
          clientY: (this.settings.startY + this.settings.max) / (2 * this.settings.max) * this.clientHeight
        };
      } else {
        this.event = {
          clientX: this.left + ((this.settings.startX + this.settings.max) / (2 * this.settings.max) * this.width),
          clientY: this.top + ((this.settings.startY + this.settings.max) / (2 * this.settings.max) * this.height)
        };
      }


      let backupScale = this.settings.scale;
      this.settings.scale = 1;
      this.update();
      this.settings.scale = backupScale;
      this.resetGlare();
    }

    getValues() {
      let x, y;

      if (this.fullPageListening) {
        x = this.event.clientX / this.clientWidth;
        y = this.event.clientY / this.clientHeight;
      } else {
        x = (this.event.clientX - this.left) / this.width;
        y = (this.event.clientY - this.top) / this.height;
      }

      x = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 1);
      y = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), 1);

      let tiltX = (this.reverse * (this.settings.max - x * this.settings.max * 2)).toFixed(2);
      let tiltY = (this.reverse * (y * this.settings.max * 2 - this.settings.max)).toFixed(2);
      let angle = Math.atan2(this.event.clientX - (this.left + this.width / 2), -(this.event.clientY - (this.top + this.height / 2))) * (180 / Math.PI);

      return {
        tiltX: tiltX,
        tiltY: tiltY,
        percentageX: x * 100,
        percentageY: y * 100,
        angle: angle
      };
    }

    updateElementPosition() {
      let rect = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();

      this.width = this.element.offsetWidth;
      this.height = this.element.offsetHeight;
      this.left = rect.left;
      this.top = rect.top;
    }

    update() {
      let values = this.getValues();

      this.element.style.transform = "perspective(" + this.settings.perspective + "px) " +
        "rotateX(" + (this.settings.axis === "x" ? 0 : values.tiltY) + "deg) " +
        "rotateY(" + (this.settings.axis === "y" ? 0 : values.tiltX) + "deg) " +
        "scale3d(" + this.settings.scale + ", " + this.settings.scale + ", " + this.settings.scale + ")";

      if (this.glare) {
        this.glareElement.style.transform = `rotate(${values.angle}deg) translate(-50%, -50%)`;
        this.glareElement.style.opacity = `${values.percentageY * this.settings["max-glare"] / 100}`;
      }

      this.element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("tiltChange", {
        "detail": values
      }));

      this.updateCall = null;
    }

    /**
     * Appends the glare element (if glarePrerender equals false)
     * and sets the default style
     */
    prepareGlare() {
      // If option pre-render is enabled we assume all html/css is present for an optimal glare effect.
      if (!this.glarePrerender) {
        // Create glare element
        const jsTiltGlare = document.createElement("div");
        jsTiltGlare.classList.add("js-tilt-glare");

        const jsTiltGlareInner = document.createElement("div");
        jsTiltGlareInner.classList.add("js-tilt-glare-inner");

        jsTiltGlare.appendChild(jsTiltGlareInner);
        this.element.appendChild(jsTiltGlare);
      }

      this.glareElementWrapper = this.element.querySelector(".js-tilt-glare");
      this.glareElement = this.element.querySelector(".js-tilt-glare-inner");

      if (this.glarePrerender) {
        return;
      }

      Object.assign(this.glareElementWrapper.style, {
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "0",
        "left": "0",
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "100%",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "pointer-events": "none"
      });

      Object.assign(this.glareElement.style, {
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "50%",
        "left": "50%",
        "pointer-events": "none",
        "background-image": `linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%)`,
        "width": `${this.element.offsetWidth * 2}px`,
        "height": `${this.element.offsetWidth * 2}px`,
        "transform": "rotate(180deg) translate(-50%, -50%)",
        "transform-origin": "0% 0%",
        "opacity": "0",
      });
    }

    updateGlareSize() {
      if (this.glare) {
        Object.assign(this.glareElement.style, {
          "width": `${this.element.offsetWidth * 2}`,
          "height": `${this.element.offsetWidth * 2}`,
        });
      }
    }

    updateClientSize() {
      this.clientWidth = window.innerWidth ||
        document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
        document.body.clientWidth;

      this.clientHeight = window.innerHeight ||
        document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
        document.body.clientHeight;
    }

    onWindowResize() {
      this.updateGlareSize();
      this.updateClientSize();
    }

    setTransition() {
      clearTimeout(this.transitionTimeout);
      this.element.style.transition = this.settings.speed + "ms " + this.settings.easing;
      if (this.glare) this.glareElement.style.transition = `opacity ${this.settings.speed}ms ${this.settings.easing}`;

      this.transitionTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.element.style.transition = "";
        if (this.glare) {
          this.glareElement.style.transition = "";
        }
      }, this.settings.speed);

    }

    /**
     * Method return patched settings of instance
     * @param {boolean} settings.reverse - reverse the tilt direction
     * @param {number} settings.max - max tilt rotation (degrees)
     * @param {startX} settings.startX - the starting tilt on the X axis, in degrees. Default: 0
     * @param {startY} settings.startY - the starting tilt on the Y axis, in degrees. Default: 0
     * @param {number} settings.perspective - Transform perspective, the lower the more extreme the tilt gets
     * @param {string} settings.easing - Easing on enter/exit
     * @param {number} settings.scale - 2 = 200%, 1.5 = 150%, etc..
     * @param {number} settings.speed - Speed of the enter/exit transition
     * @param {boolean} settings.transition - Set a transition on enter/exit
     * @param {string|null} settings.axis - What axis should be disabled. Can be X or Y
     * @param {boolean} settings.glare - What axis should be disabled. Can be X or Y
     * @param {number} settings.max-glare - the maximum "glare" opacity (1 = 100%, 0.5 = 50%)
     * @param {boolean} settings.glare-prerender - false = VanillaTilt creates the glare elements for you, otherwise
     * @param {boolean} settings.full-page-listening - If true, parallax effect will listen to mouse move events on the whole document, not only the selected element
     * @param {string|object} settings.mouse-event-element - String selector or link to HTML-element what will be listen mouse events
     * @param {boolean} settings.reset - false = If the tilt effect has to be reset on exit
     * @param {gyroscope} settings.gyroscope - Enable tilting by deviceorientation events
     * @param {gyroscopeSensitivity} settings.gyroscopeSensitivity - Between 0 and 1 - The angle at which max tilt position is reached. 1 = 90deg, 0.5 = 45deg, etc..
     * @param {gyroscopeSamples} settings.gyroscopeSamples - How many gyroscope moves to decide the starting position.
     */
    extendSettings(settings) {
      let defaultSettings = {
        reverse: false,
        max: 15,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        perspective: 1000,
        easing: "cubic-bezier(.03,.98,.52,.99)",
        scale: 1,
        speed: 300,
        transition: true,
        axis: null,
        glare: false,
        "max-glare": 1,
        "glare-prerender": false,
        "full-page-listening": false,
        "mouse-event-element": null,
        reset: true,
        gyroscope: true,
        gyroscopeMinAngleX: -45,
        gyroscopeMaxAngleX: 45,
        gyroscopeMinAngleY: -45,
        gyroscopeMaxAngleY: 45,
        gyroscopeSamples: 10
      };

      let newSettings = {};
      for (var property in defaultSettings) {
        if (property in settings) {
          newSettings[property] = settings[property];
        } else if (this.element.hasAttribute("data-tilt-" + property)) {
          let attribute = this.element.getAttribute("data-tilt-" + property);
          try {
            newSettings[property] = JSON.parse(attribute);
          } catch (e) {
            newSettings[property] = attribute;
          }

        } else {
          newSettings[property] = defaultSettings[property];
        }
      }

      return newSettings;
    }

    static init(elements, settings) {
      if (elements instanceof Node) {
        elements = [elements];
      }

      if (elements instanceof NodeList) {
        elements = [].slice.call(elements);
      }

      if (!(elements instanceof Array)) {
        return;
      }

      elements.forEach((element) => {
        if (!("vanillaTilt" in element)) {
          element.vanillaTilt = new VanillaTilt(element, settings);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
    /* expose the class to window */
    window.VanillaTilt = VanillaTilt;

    /**
     * Auto load
     */
    VanillaTilt.init(document.querySelectorAll("[data-tilt]"));
  }

  return VanillaTilt;

}());
```

```css
.container {
  width: 305px;
  height: 445px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.card {
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.front {
  background: transparent;
}

.back {
  background: transparent;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-tilt/1.7.0/vanilla-tilt.min.js" integrity="sha512-SttpKhJqONuBVxbRcuH0wezjuX+BoFoli0yPsnrAADcHsQMW8rkR84ItFHGIkPvhnlRnE2FaifDOUw+EltbuHg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="container" data-tilt data-tilt-max="10" easing="cubic-bezier(.03,.98,.52,.99)">
  <div class="card" onclick="flip(event)">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" style="height: 445px; width: 305px; border-radius: 15px; cursor: pointer;" />
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" style="height: 445px; width: 305px; border-radius: 15px; cursor: pointer;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's a tilt.js? Can you provide a working example? (please use snippet button to post code)

Comment: sure sorry i forgot :) , i've added it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggleAttribute to toggle the data-tilt-glare attribute in the flip function.

```
<div id="tiltDiv" class="container" data-tilt data-tilt-glare=true data-tilt-max="10" easing="cubic-bezier(.03,.98,.52,.99)">
```

```
document.getElementById("tiltDiv").toggleAttribute("data-tilt-glare")
```

Note: I have added an ID to the `.container` div and used that to select the element with `document.getelementbyid`

---

So, your flip function should be like this:

```
function flip(event) {
  document.getElementById("tiltDiv").toggleAttribute("data-tilt-glare");

  var element = event.currentTarget;
  if (element.className === "card") {
    if (element.style.transform == "rotateY(180deg)") {
      element.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
    } else {
      element.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
    }
  }
};
```